# Воспроизведение потокового видео Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных, videoview, online-video

Доброго времени суток. Хочу получить потоковое видео в небольшом Java-приложении, организованное с использованием swing. Перерыл весь интернет, но чего-то конкретного не нашёл. Задача такая: взять и показать видео с youtube, к примеру, в окошке. Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые реализации такого функционала, или хотя бы библиотека, которая умела декодить и воспроизводить?

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно использовать средства JavaFx для отображения видео:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VideoPlayer extends Application {    
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(
      "http://www.youtube.com/embed/flDjU_u35U0?autoplay=1"
    );
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.show();
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть открытый проект  [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/).

Это java-библиотека, работающая с видео-потоками. С её помощью можно модифицировать видео на лету.

Comment: Проект давно остановился и не развивается. Я ищу что-то более современное.

Comment: @PirateNinja На wikipedia.org есть хорошая статья о Java Media Framework https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework. Там в таблице представлены основые библиотеки, которые можно использовать (помимо Xyuggler). Возможно, что-либо сможет подойти.